# How do I get the target of a symlink?

Tags: ruby, symlink

I have a string containing the file system path to an existing symlink. I want to get the path that this link points to.

Basically I want the same that I'd get through this bit of hackery:

```
s = "path/to/existing/symlink"
`ls -ld #{s}`.scan(/-> (.+)/).flatten.last
```

but I want to do it without shelling out.

Comment: Incidentally, in bash it's also just `readlink path/to/symlink`. Never parse the output of `ls`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I think [readlink](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M002534) is what you are looking for:

```
File.readlink("path/to/symlink")
```

Comment: Note that if the symlink is relative or there is a chain of symlinks, this will not follow all the links or return the full path -Pathname#realpath will.

Comment: @mfazekas, thank you for pointing this out; I wonder whether that's really what the OP wanted though; `ls -ld ...` doesn't give the real path either.

Comment: To say it differently: This call will resolve `symlink`, but it will resolve neither `path` or `to`.

Answer (score 50):

```
require 'pathname'
Pathname.new("symlink").realpath
```

or readlink as others said

Comment: rather Pathname.new("/path/to/symlink").realpath.to_s :) .. this is definitely better than using system()

Answer (score 16):

Or you can try:

```
File.realpath("symlink_path")
```

Which works for both symlinks and normal files.