# Ruby require path

Tags: ruby, require

I have a Ruby code with different classes in a few files. In one file, I start the execution. This file `require`s my other files.

- Is this a good way to start a ruby code?
- When I run the code from a symbolic link, for example `DIR2/MyRubyCode` is a link to the main file `DIR1/MyRubyCode.rb`, then my requires will fail. I solved the problem by adding the path `DIR1` to `$LOAD_PATH` before the `require`, but I think there would be much better ways to do it. Do you have any suggestions about that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to check if a Ruby file is being '`require`'ed or executed with '`ruby MyRubyCode.rb`', check the `__FILE__` constant.

```
# If the first argument to `ruby` is this file.
if $0 == __FILE__
  # Execute some stuff.
end
```

As far as the require/$LOAD_PATH issue, you could always use the relative path in the require statement.  For example:

```
# MyRubyCode.rb
require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/foo_class"
require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/bar_module"
```

Which would include the `foo_class.rb` and `bar_module.rb` files in the same directory as `MyRubyCode.rb`.

Comment: Thanks but if I require with File.dirname(__FILE__), when I launch the code using an alias it also tries to include from '.' and I still have the 'no such file to load' error.

Comment: That is correct.  You would have to get the target of the symlink (which would go in place of `File.dirname()`).  Check out this post for a couple different ways of doing that:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237939/ruby-how-do-i-get-the-target-of-a-symlink

Comment: Thanks. It works well with `$LOAD_PATH << File.dirname(Pathname.new(File.expand_path(__FILE__)).realpath.to_s).to_s` .

Comment: For me it works only without string interpolation:
`require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/foo_class"`

Comment: use `require_relative` instead

Answer (score 18):

If you're using Ruby 1.9 or greater, user require_relative for your dependencies.

```
require_relative 'foo_class'
require_relative 'bar_module'
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but there is an updated answer to it, and I wanted to post it:

Starting in a more recent version of Ruby (I'm not sure when), you can require files in the same directory by using the following:

```
require './foo_class'
require './bar_module'
```

and it'll load files called `foo_class.rb` and `bar_module.rb` in the same directory.

For checking if your file is being `require`d or ran normally, check the other answer.

Comment: This answer does not address the use case in the original question, because it will still fail if the ruby file is being invoked from a symlink or is on the user's path.

Comment: This may not directly address the original question but it *does* come up as the first hit on Google when you're trying to figure out the right way to require files relative to a symlink.  require_relative is smart enough to know if it's a symlink and will go back relative to the original file whereas require "./" will require relative to the symlink itself, which is just what I needed.