# Trying to copy object (and not link) via RUBY Fileutils

Tags: ruby, copy, symlink

I have search a long time but didn't find the answer yet.

I'm using RUBY scripts to copy some folders and contents from a Linux station to another one.
Until now it has been done by calling Xcopy on windows (via system).

Now I have visibility on both linux station so I decided to do a regular copy via Fileutils.

My problem is that it copies sometimes link and not the objetct itself:
E.G

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 lcs rme   512 Apr  8 16:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 lcs rme   512 Apr  8 16:49 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lcs rme    67 Apr  8 16:50 FW123.h -> /rees/frme/pd/ccm_dbs1/frme/root/cache/source/#27/1681927
-rw-r--r-- 1 lcs rme 25968 Apr  8 16:50 FW123.o
```

I try several things but it never worked. In particular I tried to play with dereference_root option , but it didn't work.

do you have some clue?
thanks

Comment: I think there should be a is_link function somewhere - then you can read the file and and use the linked version.

Comment: Hum, but I have a lot of file to copy so it could take very long time to do that.

Comment: Try it out. I think there are not many symlinks. They are usually make by humans and not generated so they should be less. Sometimes you can find a "follow symlink" argument in some list directory functions. Would "copy directory and follow symlink with ruby" be a better title? then maybe more people find this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237939/ruby-how-do-i-get-the-target-of-a-symlink

Comment: In fact there is a lot. it comes from a management configuration tools that is configured to work with link instead of file. A fast count give something greater than 1000. Most of them are a few Kb but some can go up to 10 Mo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [File.realpath(pathname)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-realpath) - that will resolve symlinks.

Comment: And I realized it is a 3 year old question :D

Comment: doesn't matter, always handy for reference, but I doubt the op is still here