# Follow a chain of symlinks using Ruby

Tags: ruby, symlink

While looking at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237939/ruby-how-do-i-get-the-target-of-a-symlink), I see that the solution offered doesn't follow a chain of symlinks/regular links.

How can I do that with Ruby?

Comment: huh? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
require 'pathname'
Pathname.new("/path/to/symlink").realpath.to_s
```